# PlaylistItems.list is slow to serve the latest videos available

Tags: youtube-api, google-apis-explorer, youtube-data-api

I'm scraping the latest uploaded videos from a channel and it's working fine but I noticed that the PlaylistItems.list API is sometimes slow to offer the latest videos.
It can take days for a new video to show up on a uploaded playlist's query result.

For example:
Today, Sep 07 00:59:07 2017 UTC, [this playlistItems.list query](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=contentDetails&maxResults=5&playlistId=UUdGpd0gNn38UKwoncZd9rmA&fields=items%252FcontentDetails%252FvideoId%252C%20nextPageToken%252C%20pageInfo&_h=7&) is not returning a video posted yesterday at Sep 06 01:26:13 UTC.

The strange thing is that the API has data about the video in question, if asked about it individually using the videoId `0QlUOWbdIWw`, and the [YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QlUOWbdIWw&list=UUdGpd0gNn38UKwoncZd9rmA) also recognizes that the new video exists.

Is there a delay between the video data being available and it being included in the channel's uploaded playlist?

Edit: Although the example I posted is using anonymous requests, my app is issuing them with authentication.

Comment: I've opened an issue at Google's issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65449028

Comment: Try using this code for [retrieving uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#retrieve_my_uploads), this is a code sample for Java. As stated in this [related issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35171991), try following the  recommended method for listing all the uploaded videos in a given channel. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot The recommended approach is the one I'm using; calling `playlistItems.list` and passing the uploaded videos playlist id, instead of a simple search.
I am also using authenticated requests but that was not clear on the question so I'll update it.
Thanks!